# Nested functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In a Javascript function, are you required to define nested functions as function expressions or are function declarations allowed in a function body?  For example, would something like this be compliant?

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        function c() {
            window.alert(3);
        }
        window.alert(2);
    }
    window.alert(1);
}
```

Or would you have to do something like this?

```
function a() {
    var a = function () {
        var c = function () {
            window.alert(3);
        }
        window.alert(2);
    }
    window.alert(1);
}
```

ECMA-262 says that:

> Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support the use of  FunctionDeclaration as a Statement. However there are significant and irreconcilable variations among the implementations in the semantics applied to such FunctionDeclarations. Because of these irreconcilable differences, the use of a FunctionDeclaration as a Statement results in code that is not reliably portable among implementations. It is recommended that ECMAScript implementations either disallow this usage of FunctionDeclaration or issue a warning when such a usage is encountered. Future editions of ECMAScript may define alternative portable means for declaring functions in a Statement context.

Does this mean that a function declaration in a function body is technically incorrect, or have I got this completely wrong?  I've heard people refer to the body as a block, which according to the standard, is one or more statements, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard is, seems a bit confusing, but honestly I've never had problems nesting function declarations in IE8+ and all other browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FunctionDeclaration's are certainly allowed in function body, and there are no bugs I'm aware of.

It's all pretty clear once you look at [ES5 production rules](http://es5.github.com/#A.5)

```
FunctionBody
  SourceElements (opt)

SourceElements
  SourceElement
  SourceElements SourceElement

SourceElement
  Statement
  FunctionDeclaration
```

In other words, function body includes source elements, and source element is either a Statement or a FunctionDeclaration. Hence FunctionDeclaration can be part of a function body.

The clause you mentioned about "... implementations of ECMAScript ... known to support the use of FunctionDeclaration as a Statement" refers to using FunctionDeclaration as a Statement, but not directly in function body. It's referring to cases like:

```
if (...) {
  function f () {}
}
```

That is a non-standardized behavior. Check out more on these [function statements](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements).

Comment: Wow - Kangax - cool.  Do I remember correctly seeing something on the ES.next page about actually making block-level function declarations like this part of the language spec?

Comment: Yeah, I think they're trying to standardize this. IIRC there's also been some changes in latest engines under strict mode.